# Frontend React unable to call API due to blocked CORS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

`Profile.jsx`

```
const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/user/update/${currentUser._id}`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(formData)
        })
```

Error

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/api/user/update/651cce95aa88ef0726740018' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I am trying to call the API method that I defined on the backend server and has been blocked by cors policy. May I ask how to access the origin from the frontend in order to have two sides connected?

Comment: Just add the client IP to the origin on server side.

Comment: Just add `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` into your package.json file.

Answer (score 1):

The server should set [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) Header in the response (set it to 'localhost' or '*').
This is a security step to prevent phishing

If this is not acceptable for you to set the header you can still use an [extention](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) to disble CORS on your browser, but notice this is only a development hack

Answer (score 0):

You can install CORS in your back-end side

source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors())
 
 
app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```